# Use a NotMapped property value with Odata $filter function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, odata

I'm trying to figure out how to use a **NotMapped** property with OData

I have this **User Model**:

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
[DataMember]
public long Id { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public virtual InstagramUser InstagramUser { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public virtual FacebookUser FacebookUser { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public string InstagramID { get; set; 
}
```

And I have this **GetAll() method** in the User Controller

```
public IQueryable<User> GetAllUsers()
{
       _repository = new UserRepository();
       return _repository.GetAll().AsQueryable();
 }
```

and this **GetAll() function** in the User repository

```
public IQueryable<User> GetAll()
{
     InstaStoryDB db = new InstaStoryDB();
     var ret = db.Users.Include("InstagramUser").Include("FacebookUser").AsQueryable();
     foreach(User user in ret)
     {
        user.InstagramID = user.InstagramUser.InstagramID; //<-- I'm adding here the value to the property
     }
     return ret;         
}
```

And this is the **InstagramUser Model**

```
[DataContract]
public class InstagramUser
{
[DataMember]
public long UserId { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public string InstagramID { get; set; 
}
```

All Working good.

I did a change to the User model and added the `InstagramUser` that contain the `InstagramID`, so I added [NotMapped] attribute to remove the InstagramID from the User table in the **DB** since the InstagramUser already contain the InstagramID.

When ever I try to use Odata like this:
localhost:555/api/users/?$filter=InstagramID eq '456456546'
It's failed and return an error that the InstagramID property is not exist.

what can I do to use filter with Odata on **NotMapped** property?

Comment: I guess you cannot use `NotMapped` property. `NotMappet` property is not described in your model and so it is not available for querying when you use EF provider for OData service.

Comment: That what I thought, I'm adding a fix in the question.. can you look at it now?

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me using OData v4 in Web API:

```
var t = modelBuilder.StructuralTypes.First(x => x.ClrType == typeof(User));
t.AddProperty(typeof(User).GetProperty("InstagramID"));
```

Comment: This worked for me. I have a not-mapped get-only Details property on each of my entities where I format different properties into a string. Now OData is including them in the response.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the fix here : http://forums.asp.net/t/1887669.aspx?OData+EF+Model+with+custom+calculated+properties

1. First process the odata query manually
2. use a select query to add the notmapped property

For example

```
public IQueryable<DomainModel> GetAllDomains(ODataQueryOptions<Domains> queryOptions)
    {
        var query = queryOptions.ApplyTo(objectContext.Domains) as IQueryable<Domain>;
        return query.AsEnumerable().Select(d => new DomainModel
        {
            Name = d.Name,
            Activated = d.Activated,
            Address = d.Address,
            AdminUserName = d.AdminUserName,
            DateCreated = d.DateCreated,
            Enabled = d.Enabled,
            Subscription = (SubscriptionTypes)d.SubscriptionType,
            Website = d.Website,
            StatsUpdatePending = d.StatsUpdatePending,
            LastHousekeeping = d.LastHousekeeping,
            CalculatedProperty = calculator.Calculate(d.Name, d.Activated)
        }).AsQueryable();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mate, But it's been 2 years and I don't have an option to check this solution. I will up vote you for your time :)
Thanks!

Comment: No problem, i just saw there where no answers... So, this is better then nothing :p

Comment: If you try to pass `$filter=contains(CalculatedProperty, 'x')` you get the exception: `The specified type member 'CalculatedProperty' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

Comment: Then you didn't do: AsEnumerable()

Because AsEnumerable() converts it  to Linq To Objects and not Linq to Entities. If i'm not mistaking ( it's been > 3 years), the query was not applied to the NotMapped property. It is when it's Enumerable(), or something changed between the odata versions.

Answer (score 3):

I found a similar solution to Jason Steele one but using the methods EntityType and Property like this:

```
modelBuilder.EntityType<User>().Property(u => u.InstagramID);
```

There result is the same. If you look at the source code of the Property method, you will find that it is getting the PropertyInfo and then adding it to the StructuralTypeConfiguration of that class:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = PropertySelectorVisitor.GetSelectedProperty(propertyExpression);
PrimitivePropertyConfiguration property = _configuration.AddProperty(propertyInfo);
```